# How to delete text from a textbox from starting to first "," comma in a sentence?

Tags: string, vb.net

I want to delete all the words in a textbox from starting to the first comma appearance.

Example -

> Ram bought rice, bread and tomatoes.

The above sentence should become -

> bread and tomatoes.

I know how to replace texts in VB.Net but I can't find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Dim s As String = "Ram bought rice, bread and tomatoes."
    Dim index As Integer = s.IndexOf(",") + 1
    Dim substring As String = s.Substring(index , s.Length - index)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how to do it.

```
Module Example

    Sub Main()
        Dim str As String = "foo, bar baz"
        Dim index As Integer = str.IndexOf(",") + 1
        Dim length As Integer = str.Length - index
        str = str.Substring(index, length)
        Console.WriteLine(str)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: That doesn't compile.  It also throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: I made some syntax errors and i didn't test the code.
I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but here is how I would do it using a function.

```
Private Function Foo(ByVal str As String) As String

    If str.Contains(",") Then
        Return str.Split(",")(1).Trim()
    End If
    ''return nothing as the user only wants the 2nd half of the string
    Return Nothing

End Function
```

`Trim()` will remove any leading spaces.
You can call the function like so,

```
Dim value As String = "Ram bought rice, bread and tomatoes."
textBox1.Text = Foo(value)
```

Output: `bread and tomatoes.`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are nice, but adding the 2nd parameter gives an un-needed risk. Try this for safer code

```
Dim MyString As String = "Ram bought rice, bread and tomatoes."
Dim index As Integer = MyString.IndexOf(",") + 1
Dim MyNewString As String = MyString.Substring(index)
```

This just uses the first parameter, as the second calculation to calculate the length is not needed.